# Data Types for encrypted data in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, encryption, sqldatatypes

I'm struggling to understand how encryption works when storing the values in MYSQL. If I was storing customer data I would have Address Line columns, Postcode column etc. and with this I would for example use these data types:

Column 1: Address Line 1 - VARCHAR(100),
Column 4: Postcode - VARCHAR(8), 
Column 5: Telephone - VARCHAR(15)

However once this data has been encrypted would the data type have to be different, for example a blob?
Also what would I need to adapt if I used AES-256 bit encryption instead of AES-128 bit encryption? Could anyone help me understand how this works? Thank you

Comment: [Why shouldn't we roll our own?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197)

Comment: What are you trying to protect here, and who are you trying to protect it from?

Comment: I want to protect customer addresses with their name and just all other sorts of sensitive data such as passwords. Protect from cyber attacks. I can do databases just never understood how encryption works.

Comment: Where will you store the key?  The application needs the key to use the data, so a "cyber attack" that corrupts the application will have just as much access to the (decrypted) data.  Passwords should be salted and (irreversibly) hashed, so they can be verified without ever being retrieved.

Comment: Ok I guess you're telling me there is no need to encrypt this type of data? I'm confused more than I was before so what data should I encrypt and what data should I not encrypt? And what is the best protection to use?

Comment: A sufficiently well-resourced attacker can eventually defeat any security you choose to have.  Your goals are therefore to put in place security that is sufficient to put your assets beyond the economic reach of any likely attackers. To do that, you first need to identify who the attackers are, what resources they will have, what assets (information/systems) they will be targeting and what their objectives will be (data theft/corruption/denial of service). Then you can consider how much resource you're willing to put into defending those attacks. Only THEN can you start identifying solutions.

Comment: Ok so first thing I've found is this http://www.informationsecuritybuzz.com/articles/data-breach-in-your-crm-system-do-you-know-the-risks/

Comment: Am I on the right path?

Comment: Encryption is mentioned in that article therefore is it right that I need to encrypt my customer data?

Comment: Where will you keep the key?  That can be the weakest link in encryption.

Comment: In a separate database. Each tenant has it's own database schema. Another database will hold tenant info with a different key for each. Guard the key database with all it takes. Would something like that work?

Comment: On a separate server aswell can I add

Answer (score 1):

If you have MySQL Enterprise Edition, you must utilize Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) option of MySQL.

This does 2 things:

1. It encrypts the data at rest.
2. It separate Key Storage and stores in external source using known protocols

By using this, your existing code base would have minimalist code changes, but still achieve encrypted data storage more details can be found at

https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/tde.html